# Regex to select and replace stuff, keeping patterns

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to change some strings:

```
space+cows       -->    space + cows
stupid+rabbit    -->    stupid + rabbit

(put spaces around the `+`)
```

In Sublime Text 2, I tried to use these:

```
Find:    \w+\+\w+
Replace: \w+ \+ \w+
```

The finding *regex* matched everything well, but obviously, my strings were replaced with literally
`w+ + w+`.

One more example:

```
Strings:
bool *foo        -->    bool* foo
int *bar         -->    int* bar

Pattern:
Find:    (bool|int) *(foo|bar)
Replace: (bool|int)* (foo|bar)

Result:
(bool|int)* (foo|bar)
(bool|int)* (foo|bar)
```

Needless to say I wanted to keep the actual `bool`, `int`, `foo` and `bar` as they were before.
I also cannot use only `­ \*` to match the strings because it would select other stuff that I don't want to replace; I need some context around the actual `­ \*` to select the correct strings. In the same way, I cannot use patterns like `­ \*[^ ­ ]` because the *not-space* character after the asterisk would be obliterated after replacement.

I fixed my problem by using Sublime Text's multiline edition but I am still wondering: is it possible to use a *regex* in such a way that you can replace strings containing "group of characters" without wiping the actual contents of the "group of characters"?

Comment: You can practice basic regex problems here: https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs

Comment: That's great, I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The reason your replacements don't work is (as you've noticed) your replacement text is just literal text; whatever you put in the box is what replaces what was matched as you would expext.

What you need to do is use a [RegEx capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) for this. What this does is make the regular expression processor (in this case Sublime Text) not only match the test but also store it for use in the replacement. You do that by wrapping the parts of the match you want to save in parenthesis. Each set of parenthesis is a `Capture Group`.

For your example, your regex becomes"

```
(\w+)\+(\w+)
```

The value of the match inside each set of parenthesis is saved into it's own numeric group, starting at one. A syntax like the following expands out to the contents of the first match, followed by the plus sign with spaces around it, followed by the second word:

```
\1 + \2
```

You can use each number multiple times, if you want:

```
\1 and again \1 and also \2
```

Comment: Wow I'm actually surprised it *is* possible... I thought I was asking too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regex to turn `"stupid+rabbit" to "stupid + rabbit"`

```
Find: (\w+)\+(\w+)
Replace: $1 + $2
```

Regex to turn `"bool *foo" or "int *bar" into "bool* foo" or "int* bar"`

```
Find: (bool|int) \*(foo|bar)
Replace: $1* $2
```

() - forms groups which can be later used. $1 is the first group and $2 is the second group.